# the meaning of "need not be uniquely determined"

Tags: meaning

i don't understand the meaning of the "even" and "need not be uniquely determined" in this phrase:
True, even the will of supporters of particular parties is still likely to be multidimensional, so partisan interest need not be uniquely determined

Answer (score 1):

As I read it, it's saying that individuals have opinions about various policies, so that they aren't necessarily totally in agreement with any one political party. You might expect a supporter of a party to agree with every point in that party's platform, but you would be wrong, because the supporter's will is multidimensional. So "even" means "contrary to expectation." "Need not be uniquely determined" could mean that the supporter's choice of party isn't necessarily the party that he or she agrees with on one issue; or it could mean that although someone supports a party, their position on any one issue isn't necessarily the same as the party's official position. More context would be needed to decide which.

Answer (score 0):

Reconstructing the statement and rebuilding it, I could interpret it as follows:

Truth is that taking into consideration the will of supporters of particular parties is still likely to lead to argumentations supported by several different viewpoints...

So a partisan interest does not need to be so straight or pre-determined by a specific condition or by pre-made argumentation that might already exist within his/her party's collective consciousness.

Answer (score 0):

To 'uniquely determine' partisan interest is to find out exactly what each person's partisan interest is as you ask the other questions.  Then you could say that 48 percent of those that were in this party thought X.

The writer is saying that their survey questions' answers would be of interest even without such a determination.  Presumably they didn't ask such a question, or instead asked other questions that might lead to a probable party determination, such as age, point of view on other questions.